# Probability of I passengers sitting randomly but in their actual assigned seats

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There was a question that came up in my practice:

> If there are N passengers on a full flight who sit in random seats,
> what is the probability that i passengers sit in their assigned seats?

The answer is supposed to be $ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (-1)^j {n\choose i+j} \frac{(n-(i+j)!)}{n!}$

But I don't understand where the expression came from. I'd love if someone could explain it step-by-step.

Comment: are you aware of derrangements??

Comment: Some of the errors and typos aside, your expression seems more like _at least_ $i$ passengers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of the Derangement problem. Recall that the derangement formula tells us that the number of ways $n$ objects can be arranged in $n$ places so that none of the objects land up in their respective places is $$D(n)=!n=n!\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

Now we use this in our problem. The number of ways that exactly $i$ people sit at their respective places and the rest $n-i$ people sit at incorrect places will hence turn out to be $${n \choose i}D(n-i)={n \choose i}(n-i)!\sum_{j=0}^{n-i} \frac{(-1)^j}{j!}$$ (choosing any $i$ objects from $n$ and deranging the rest)

Now the number of ways that at least $i$ people sit at their correct places will simply be summing this up from $i$ till $n-1$. You can finish the rest.